# How do I get all the columns name from KendoGrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I need all the names of the kendo grid to perform some operations in the grid. Please help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the follwing code.

```
  var columnsNames ="";
  var columns = $("#CircuitGrid").data("kendoGrid").columns;
        if (columns.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                var col = columns[i];
                if (col.field != undefined) {
                    if (columnsNames.length < 1)
                        columnsNames = col.field;
                    else
                        columnsNames += "~" + col.field;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log("columnsNames = " + columnsNames);
```

Write the code on the event (lets suppose on a button click) where you want the Columns name.

Comment: Thanks bro.. Exactly what I want.. :)

Comment: col.title can also be used to get the column titles.